# Delay or make callback when binding data in UI5

Tags: sapui5

i want to show message after binding data but message always shown before binding complete and show the result on the bound table. I want to delay or make callback when binding data is finished.
Thanks for help.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("sap/opu/odata/sap/*SRV/");
var oSummaryTable = sap.ui.getCore().byId("oSummaryTable");
oSummaryTable.setModel(oModel);
sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("Succeed");
```

Comment: What kind of table is the `oSummaryTable`? sap.m or sap.ui.table?

Answer (score 0):

```
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
    sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("Succeed");
});
```

Comment: I tried this code but it didn't work the message appear before loading complete

Comment: Maybe try 
`sap.ui.getCore().byId("oSummaryTable").onAfterRendering(function() {
     sap.ui.commons.MessageBox.alert("Succeed");
});`